# Cygwin header files

Tags: cygwin

I have just installed Cygwin on my 64 bit Windows 10. I need sys/types.h, sys/socket.h and several other libraries. However, I can't find these files under the cygwin installation directory. Where can I get them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those are part of the *cygwin-devel* package:

```sh
$ apt-cyg listfiles cygwin-devel | egrep 'sys/(types|socket).h'
usr/include/sys/types.h
usr/include/sys/socket.h
```